# How to Modify exiting csv column in ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file. in csv some fields are blank. i want to update these fields with some value. I have try following but no luck.

```
CSV.foreach("/home/mypc/Desktop/data.csv", { encoding: "UTF-8", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all}).with_index do |row,i|
   if row[:images].nil?
      row[:images] << ['im1']
   end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
row[:images] ||= "im1"
```

will set the `images` cell of your row to `"im1"` if it's empty.

If you want to write a new CSV file with updated cells, you could use :

```
require 'csv'

write_parameters = { write_headers: true, headers: %w(images name) }
read_parameters  = { encoding: 'UTF-8',
                     headers: true,
                     header_converters: :symbol,
                     converters: :all }

CSV.open('new_data.csv', 'w+', write_parameters) do |new_csv|
  CSV.foreach('data.csv', read_parameters) do |row|
    row[:images] ||= 'im1'
    new_csv << row
  end
end
```

With `data.csv` :

```
images,name
im2,name2
im3,name3
,name1
im4,name4
im5,
```

`new_data.csv` becomes :

```
images,name
im2,name2
im3,name3
im1,name1
im4,name4
im5,
```

If you're **sure** that `new_data.csv` is properly written, you could delete `data.csv` and rename `new_data.csv` to `data.csv`.

I wouldn't write `data.csv` in place. If anything goes wrong, you'd lose data.